# how to create a sqlite database in windows phone 8

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8

I am new to windows phone development.I want to create a sqlite database and insert the value in to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing, I suggest you please do some Google search before posting question, but it's ok. You can follow [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/andy_wigley/archive/2013/06/06/sqlite-winrt-database-programming-on-windows-phone-and-windows-8.aspx) and also [here](http://developer.nokia.com/Community/Wiki/How_to_use_SQLite_in_Windows_Phone) for your question. Hope it helps you.